# Change "No Product" message in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, message

I have the problem at the first Woocommerce page. I don't have any product at the shop. For this reason, Woocommerce shows "No Products" message on the first page. Now I want to change this message. How do I do this?

[image]

Shop address: http://shahroodantenna.ir/shop/

Answer (score 13):

Try the following, where you can customize the "No Product" message:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found', function(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found', 'wc_no_products_found', 10 );

    // HERE change your message below
    $message = __( 'No products were found matching your selection.', 'woocommerce' );

    echo '<p class="woocommerce-info">' . $message .'</p>';
}, 9 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Does this still work in 2021? I tried it but it doesn't.

Comment: @Zanam Just tested that on WooCommerce last version and it still works perfectly… [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkGLj.png)

Comment: Why not just change the template? /templates/loop/no-products-found.php

Answer (score 2):

Copy the file: /plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/no-products-found.php to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/no-products-found.php and change as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could achieve this in two ways:

1. overriding the no-products-foun2 template on your child theme (see: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ - https://woocommerce.com/2015/12/site-search-nothing-found/)
2. (easier) use "Say What" plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/ - It allows you to replace the desired string with the text you desire

With the second option, you can customize only the copy. Going with the first one, you have more freedom to insert pictures, a search form, etc...