# Display a message if there are no products returned for a WooCommerce shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I have a page using the shortcode `[products columns="4" category="free-prize-draws"]` to show products in a specific category. If there are no products in that category, the page is blank.

Is it possible to have the page display a message if there are no products returned for a product shortcode? In the same way that a message is displayed if there are no search results for a particular search query.

Comment: Check where this shortcode call and add condition `empty($products)`

Comment: @RobinSingh How would I do that? it's not in the WooCommerce shortcode documentation page

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177110/change-no-product-message-in-woocommerce

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe thanks, I already have the 'no products' message customised, the problem I have is that if no products are returned when using a shortcode it doesn't show any message at all, just a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `do_action( "woocommerce_shortcode_{$this->type}_loop_no_results", $this->attributes );` action hook.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results( $attributes ) {
    echo __( 'My custom message', 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results', 'action_woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: This action won't work if we use `on_sale=true` in our shortcode

Comment: PS. this issue is describe here --> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/29308